# how to grep below sql part from db2 error log

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, aix

I have a script which extract error messages from db2diag.log. I have to extract the SQL queries which caused the deadlock from the below file.

File contents: `log.txt`

```
db2inst1 , WSCOMUSR , MESSAGE : ADM5501I  DB2 is performing lock escalation. The affected application 
          is named "db2jcc_application", and is associated with the workload 
          name "SYSDEFAULTUSERWORKLOAD" and application ID 
          "173.10.105.33.59586.13011817552"  at member "0". The total number of 
          locks currently held is "1249935", and the target number of locks to 
          hold is "624967". The current statement being executed is "delete 
           from DMEXPLOG where CREATED < ? ". Reason code "1"


db2inst1 , WSCOMUSR , MESSAGE : ADM5501I  DB2 is performing lock escalation. The affected application 
          is named "db2jcc_application", and is associated with the workload 
          name "SYSDEFAULTUSERWORKLOAD" and application ID 
          "173.10.105.33.59586.13011817552"  at member "0". The total number of 
          locks currently held is "1249935", and the target number of locks to 
          hold is "624967". The current statement being executed is "select 
          * from DMEXPLOG where CREATED < ?". Reason code "1"
```

Required output: all the sql queries

```
1. delete 
           from DMEXPLOG where CREATED < ?
2. select 
          * from DMEXPLOG where CREATED < ?
```

like this. I want all sql parts from the file. Any `grep` or Awk/`sed` solution to get required output?

Platform: Unix (AIX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current example can be translated with

```
sed -n '/statement being executed/ s/.*"//p; /Reason code/ s/".*//p'  log
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub(/^.*The current statement being executed is \"|\". Reason code.*$/,""); print NR". "$0}' log.txt
1. delete from DMEXPLOG where CREATED < ? 
2. 
3. select * from DMEXPLOG where CREATED < ?
```

The matching strings could be shorter no doubt and 2. is empty because the data you presented had an empty line between the actual data. Are there empty lines in the actual data?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, This help you

```
 user@host:/tmp$ sed -n '/select/,/^$/p;/delete/,/^$/p;/insert/,/^$/p;/update/,/^$/p' log.txt | sed -n '/^[0-9]/!H;//x;$x;s/\n\([^A]\)/ \1/gp' | awk -F'"' '{printf("%d.\t %s\n", NR, $4)}'
1.   delete             from DMEXPLOG where CREATED < ? 
2.   select            * from DMEXPLOG where CREATED < ?
```